# Finding the kink in a bivariate relationship

Tags: r, clustering, discriminant-analysis, threshold, supervised-learning

I'm investigating which methods are generally used to dichotomise an ordinal variable Y so that it maximises the between-group differences in the values of X and minimises the within-group differences in the values of X. Basically I want some kind of optimal (binary) binning of my variable Y (ordinal, ranging from let's say 0 to 8) according to values of variable X (a continuous variable).

I've created some data where I would say the optimal line is at 3: the main grouping in respect to X is between those with a Y score 0 to 3 and those with a score of 4 to 6. Obviously the real data would contain a lot more noise, but the data below should be useful for clarifying what I'm working with and particularly the non-linear relationship I find between my X and Y. Basically it's about finding the kink in the bivariate relationship, or where the relationship reaches a plateau (see plot):

R code

```
     D<-data.frame(rbind(cbind(rep(0,600),rnorm(600,mean=2000,sd=2)),
                            cbind(rep(1,600),rnorm(600,mean=1000,sd=2)),
                            cbind(rep(2,300),rnorm(300,mean=500,sd=2)),
                            cbind(rep(3,200),rnorm(200,mean=200,sd=2)),
                            cbind(rep(4,99),rnorm(99,mean=50,sd=2)),
                            cbind(rep(5,98),rnorm(98,mean=45,sd=2)),
                            cbind(rep(6,90),rnorm(90,mean=43,sd=2)),
                            cbind(rep(7,90),rnorm(90,mean=44,sd=2)),
                            cbind(rep(8,85),rnorm(85,mean=41,sd=2))
                            ))
#And a couple of other datasets but with slightly different distribution (but same kink)

    n<-600
    D2<-data.frame(rbind(cbind(rep(0,600),rnorm(600,mean=2000,sd=2)),
    cbind(rep(1,n),rnorm(n,mean=1000,sd=2)),cbind(rep(2,n),rnorm(n,mean=500,sd=2)),
    cbind(rep(3,n),rnorm(n,mean=200,sd=2)),cbind(rep(4,n),rnorm(n,mean=50,sd=2)),
    cbind(rep(5,n),rnorm(n,mean=45,sd=2)),cbind(rep(6,n),rnorm(n,mean=43,sd=2)),
    cbind(rep(7,n),rnorm(n,mean=44,sd=2)),cbind(rep(8,n),rnorm(n,mean=41,sd=2))))

D3<-data.frame(rbind(cbind(rep(0,600),rnorm(600,mean=2000,sd=2)),
cbind(rep(1,600),rnorm(600,mean=1000,sd=2)),cbind(rep(2,300),rnorm(300,mean=500,sd=2)),
cbind(rep(3,200),rnorm(200,mean=200,sd=2)), cbind(rep(4,200),rnorm(200,mean=50,sd=2)),
cbind(rep(5,200),rnorm(200,mean=45,sd=2)),cbind(rep(6,200),rnorm(200,mean=43,sd=2)),
cbind(rep(7,200),rnorm(200,mean=44,sd=2)),cbind(rep(8,300),rnorm(300,mean=41,sd=2))))

  colnames(D)<-colnames(D2)<-colnames(D3)<-c("Y","X")   
      plot(D)
```

I'm not interested in graphical approximations, plotting secant lines or splines but instead in robust techniques which carry out formal statistical tests to find the best binary binning, and I would be very grateful if you could give me your thoughts on this and if you have a solution provide code to apply to the data above.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Keeping the data as they arrive minimises within-group differences at 0. More generally, what exactly is your criterion (please write down an equation)? Why do you want to throw away information?

Comment: You will have to specify your measures of between-group and within-group differences, and the trade-offs you are willing to make between those two types of differences. Those choices are probably best informed by your knowledge of the underlying subject matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to solve this.

a) find the line that joins the two extremum 
points (along D$X) of your sample.
b) compute the orthogonal distance of all points 
to this line. 
c) the point most below this line is where the kink is.

Here is a simple R code to illustrate this.

```
plot(D$X,D$Y)
#the two extrem points
a1<-which.min(D$X)     
a2<-which.max(D$X)
a1<-c(D$X[a1],D$Y[a1])
a2<-c(D$X[a2],D$Y[a2])
a0<-rbind(a1,a2)
points(a0,col="red",pch=16)
#find the line joining them.
a3<-lm(a0[,2]~a0[,1])$coef
a4<-c(-a3[2],1)
a4<-a4/sqrt(sum(a4**2))
#find the point furthest below (orthogonaly) to this line:
a5<-which.min(cbind(D$X,D$Y)%*%a4)
#the kink:
points(t(c(D$X[a5],D$Y[a5])),col="green",pch=16)
```

[image: The kink in green]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Isn't this highly dependent on the cumulative distribution though? I've tweaked Dataset D-see D2 and D3 above and added a few more cases at the bottom and I obtain very different results even if the kind remains the same          `s1<-lmrob.control(); 
s1$subsampling<-"simple"; 
s1$maxit.scale<-10000;
aa<-lmrob(D2$Y~D2$X,control=s1); bb<-which(abs(aa$resid)/aa$scale>2.5); plot(D2$X,D2$Y); points(D2$X[bb],D2$Y[bb],col="red",pch=16); abline(aa$coef)` D3 also returns slightly different results

Comment: Apologies I meant 'even if the same kink remains'